# I can't successfully install postgreSQL. 'Problem running post-install step' error message pops up

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows-8

I have successfully installed postgreSQL previously, but I am struggling to install it in one particular machine (Windows 8.1 Pro). Everytime I try to install it I get the following message:

```
Warning
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed.
```

After the above message pops up the installation completes, but there's no postgreSQL service at all on the services list in the task manager.

I know that an older version of postgreSQL used to run without problems in this machine. Maybe uninstallation was not done properly? Has anyone seen this message before?

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version are you installing?

Comment: There is a sibling question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20296688/3270427

Comment: Check out this Video, I successfully able to install it. After following the video,you have to run pgadmin as administrator if you are not an administrator. Video name in Youtube: INSTALL postgresSQL, pgAdmin and PostGIS SUCCESSFULLY || AVOID INSTALLATION ERROR (2020) Link to the Videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKG0UnnyH7U